# 404 NOT FOUND in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am creating a simple website in `Laravel` while running a web site ran into the problem with `404 NOT FOUND Laravel 8`. index page working when I click on **about us** and **contact us** page getting error of `404 NOT FOUND` I don't know why is that. what I tried so far I attached below.

**Folder structure**

[image]

**Controller**

```
class SmsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }  


    public function aboutus()
    {
        return view('aboutus');
    }  

    public function contactus()
    {
        return view('contactus');
    }  


}
```

**Index.blade.php** I made the links

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('aboutus')}}">Aboutus</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('contactus')}}">Contactus</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@Index');
Route::get('Aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@aboutus');
Route::get('Contactus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@contactus');
```

Comment: `aboutus` !=  `Aboutus` fixed those and `contactus` != `Contactus`

Comment: Route::get('Aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@Aboutus');
Route::get('Contactus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@Contactus'); i changed like this but still the same error

Comment: Maybe you need add slash?  for example: `Route::get('/Aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@aboutus');`

Comment: `C` to `c`  and `A` to `a` |||||||  `url('aboutus')` this is not `Route::get('Aboutus',`

Comment: Its a typo, will be `<li><a href="{{url('Aboutus')}}">Aboutus</a></li>   <li><a href="{{url('Contactus')}}">Contactus</a></li>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you got error here

```
Route::get('Aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@aboutus');
Route::get('Contactus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@contactus');
```

instead

```
Route::get('/aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@aboutus');
Route::get('/contactus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@contactus');
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this command:

`php artisan route:cache`

then

`php artisan serve`

After that, copy the IP address after second command.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 8 you can try this way:

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\SmsController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/about-us', [App\Http\Controllers\SmsController::class, 'aboutus']);
Route::get('/contact-us', [App\Http\Controllers\SmsController::class, 'contactus']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `php artisan route:cach` command in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In my laravel 9 case, I added a new attribute style routes and it gave 404 error, from console writing

```
`php artisan route:clear`
```

has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to write a route like this

`Route::get('/aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@aboutus');`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I have been on this for close to two days, this is what helped me

php artisan route:cache

using v9

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the route address since the Laravel route are case sensitive.

the correct form of route

```
Route::get('/aboutus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@aboutus');
Route::get('/contactus', 'App\Http\Controllers\SmsController@contactus')'
```

and also it is worth mentioning that the **updated** accepted way to write routes in the `Laravel 8.x` to-class method is

```
Route::get('/aboutus', [App\Http\Controllers\SmsController::class, 'aboutus']);
Route::get('/contactus', [App\Http\Controllers\SmsController::class, 'contactus']);
```

but the old method is still accessible on the newer version of Laravel