# search routing in laravel 8, error " page not found "

Tags: laravel, routes

What should be the route for the search page in laravel 8? My routes are...

[image]

List of routes :

[image]

Redirect that I use in the search method in the controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeG6Z.png)

please can someone help me I'm blocked?

Comment: please add code instead of picture

Comment: Add search route lines before resource routes in web.php

Comment: does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332325/404-not-found-in-laravel-8

Answer (score 0):

with get method, you've called two times `/search` URL.

The first is for `personnel` and the second is for `material`. While running `route:list` personnel route override by `material`. Hence, It show only last route.

You should have one URL for any route.

```
Route('/search/{type}',MaterialController@search)->name('type.search');
```

Now you can use it in a dynamic way.

```
{{ url('search/material')}}
{{ url('search/personnel')}}
{{ route('type.search','material')}}
{{ route('type.search','personnel')}}
```

In the controller, you can make it as dynamic as below.

```
public function invoicestorecentiga($type) {
    if($type == 'material'){
    }
    if($type == 'personnel'){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two same `search` routes in your `web.php` file. Even if you named them differently, your second `search` route is overwriting the first one, and the first route basically doesn't exist anymore. My suggestion would be to rename one of those routes to something else, example:

```
Route::get('materials/search', ....)
Route::get('personnel/search', ....)
```